# Replace some string with delimited text

Tags: python, sublimetext2, notepad++

I have some string "zyzyzy" at multiple places in a html file. The number of occurences is 1100.

I need to replace these with vertical bar(|) delimited text that I have kept in a separate text file.

The length of each delimited text ranges from one to hundreds characters.

How can it be done using python-script, notepad++, sublime text or whatever way. 
If I do it manually I will have to copy-paste 1100 times in each file.

This is a python-script to replace content using Notepad++ python-script plugin; which arguments should I pass to content.replace function.

```
content = editor.getText()
while "zyzyzy" in content:
    content = content.replace("zyzyzy", ?? )
 /*which arguments should I pass here in place of '??' */

notepad.new()
editor.addText(content)
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you will have to write some code.. Which is good, because otherwise this question would be offtopic. Do you know any python?

Comment: @Blorgbeard I added some python-script; I have only little programming knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hacked together a python script which seems to work.

```
# load the pipe-delimited replacements into a list
with open ("c:\\pipes.txt", "r") as myfile:
    pipes=myfile.read().split('|')

# keep track of which replacement we are up to
ix = 0

def processmatch(line, match):
    # we want to use these variables which were declared outside the function
    global ix
    global pipes
    # if we still have replacement text to use..
    if ix < len(pipes):
        # replace this match text with the current replacement
        editor.setTargetStart(editor.positionFromLine(line) + match.start())
        editor.setTargetEnd(editor.positionFromLine(line) + match.end())
        editor.replaceTarget(pipes[ix])
        # use the next replacement next time
        ix += 1

# everything the script does will be undone with a single ctrl+Z
editor.beginUndoAction()

# call processmatch for every instance of the target text
editor.pysearch('zyzyzy', processmatch)

editor.endUndoAction()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use sublime's multi selections. If you don't have the binding already, then add this to your keybinding file:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+d"], "command": "find_all_under" },
```

Copy the delimited text. Select first occurance of `zyzyzy`, hit `ctrl+alt+d`, paste. Done.